# C# If....Else statement ignoring the condition

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
Console.WriteLine("What type of calculation do you want to perform? (+, -, *, /, %)");
        V = Console.ReadLine();

        if (V == "+" && V == "-" && V == "*" && V == "/" && V == "%")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of y");
            y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid operator type");
        }
```

for some reason, it ignores the condition, and whatever I type as a value of V it still asks me to enter the value of y.
Ps: I'm a beginner obviously, I searched everywhere why this happens  and I couldn't find any answers, I hope someone can help me out

Comment: Your are using "and" (&&) operator, it means that your V variable must be "+" and "-" and "*" in the SAME time. Your should change сomparison to "or" operator (||) or imho better, make a collection of operators and after u can write something like this: if (operators.Contains(v)) ...

Comment: Even if you entered any of the valid inputs you would be prompted to enter a valid operator because `V` cannot possibly be all of the valid inputs based on your condition. It can only be `+` or `-` or `*` or `/` or `%`, not  `+` and `-` and `*` and `/` and `%`.

Comment: Read your if condition out loud. _If `V` is `'+'` AND `V` is `'-'` AND etc_. Can you think of any value of `V` that can simultaneously be all those values? Use `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: I changed "&&" to "||" but nothing changed i still have the same problem

Comment: I just pasted your code in to VS2019 and ran it. I entered a dollar sign (not a valid operator type) and I received the proper "Enter a valid operator type" response. Looks like it's working to me!

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint to see if you're actually running that code instead of a stale compiled cache

Comment: Are you sure you get just an operator back, and not the operator with `\r\n` (newline in windows)?  You might instead want to `Trim()` the result of `ReadLine` (to remove whitespace characters which don't change the meaning but do cause testing mis-match).

Comment: I'd just put a breakpoint on the if and check what's in `V`.

Comment: Please check the solution  http://tpcg.io/K7i9VTdM and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: It still doesnt work

Comment: here is the whole solution [link](https://rextester.com/KDP26090)

Comment: Pasting your current code in, it runs fine and as I would expect. Note that by editing the question from && to ||, you invalidated the question. Not a good practice.

Comment: @EricJ. is right. Changing the question with an edit like that is so bad a violation of community standards that I've rolled back the question to your original version. Please don't change that part again. The question becomes _completely_ different if you fix the code that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please use || instead of && because variable V cannot have all these values at the same time **(V == "+" && V == "-" && V == "*" && V == "/" && V == "%")**.

Try the following link, it is working.

http://tpcg.io/K7i9VTdM

```
    string V;
    int y;
```

[image]

Comment: I just did that but i still face the same problem

Comment: please try small v instead of capital V

Comment: Changing the case of the variable wouldn't change anything here.

Comment: Typecasting would work?

Comment: Typecasting what to what?

Comment: In fact when I tried so it was giving error The name `V' does not exist in the current context, The name `y' does not exist in the current context

Comment: here is the whole solution [link](https://rextester.com/KDP26090)

Comment: `V` isn't declared in the originally posted code.